# underlining will only work if I change the object another way

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fabricjs

I'm using the following code to manipulate IText objects in fabric.js. They all work, but the underline doesn't display itself until after I've selected another style to apply to the object.

In other words, I'll

1. underline an element (but underlining does not display)
2. select Bold, for example, and the underlining displays, as well as the bold

Here's my code:

```
// Text Styles
function addHandler(id, fn, eventName) {
  document.getElementById(id)[eventName || 'onclick'] = function() {
    var el = this;
    if (obj = canvas.getActiveObject()) {
      fn.call(el, obj);
      canvas.renderAll();
    }
  };
}
function setStyle(object, styleName, value) {
  if (object.setSelectionStyles && object.isEditing) {
    var style = { };
    style[styleName] = value;
    object.setSelectionStyles(style);
  }
  else {
    object[styleName] = value;
  }
}
function getStyle(object, styleName) {
  return (object.getSelectionStyles && object.isEditing)
    ? object.getSelectionStyles()[styleName]
    : object[styleName];
}
// bold
addHandler('bold', function(obj) {
  var isBold = (getStyle(obj, 'fontWeight') || '').indexOf('bold') > -1;
  setStyle(obj, 'fontWeight', isBold ? '' : 'bold');
});
// italic
addHandler('italic', function(obj) {
  var isItalic = (getStyle(obj, 'fontStyle') || '').indexOf('italic') > -1;
  setStyle(obj, 'fontStyle', isItalic ? '' : 'italic'); 
});
// underline
addHandler('underline', function(obj) {
  var isUnderline = (getStyle(obj, 'textDecoration') || '').indexOf('underline') > -1;
  setStyle(obj, 'textDecoration', isUnderline ? '' : 'underline');
});
```

And the buttons I'm using to toggle the styles are:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" id="bold" style="font-weight: bold;">Bold</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" id="italic" style="text-decoration: italic;"><em>Italic</em></a>
<a class="dropdown-item" id="underline" style="text-decoration: underline;">Underline</a>
```

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: Hi @Durga I'm using 1.7.20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `obj.dirty = true;` in your underline handler.

**DEMO**

```js
// Text Styles
function addHandler(id, fn, eventName) {
  document.getElementById(id)[eventName || 'onclick'] = function() {
    var el = this;
    if (obj = canvas.getActiveObject()) {
      fn.call(el, obj);
      canvas.renderAll();
    }
  };
}

function setStyle(object, styleName, value) {
  if (object.setSelectionStyles && object.isEditing) {
    var style = {};
    style[styleName] = value;
    object.setSelectionStyles(style);
  } else {
    object[styleName] = value;
  }
}

function getStyle(object, styleName) {
  return (object.getSelectionStyles && object.isEditing) ?
    object.getSelectionStyles()[styleName] :
    object[styleName];
}
// bold
addHandler('bold', function(obj) {
  var isBold = (getStyle(obj, 'fontWeight') || '').indexOf('bold') > -1;
  setStyle(obj, 'fontWeight', isBold ? '' : 'bold');
});
// italic
addHandler('italic', function(obj) {
  var isItalic = (getStyle(obj, 'fontStyle') || '').indexOf('italic') > -1;
  setStyle(obj, 'fontStyle', isItalic ? '' : 'italic');
});
// underline
addHandler('underline', function(obj) {
  var isUnderline = (getStyle(obj, 'textDecoration') || '').indexOf('underline') > -1;
  setStyle(obj, 'textDecoration', isUnderline ? '' : 'underline');
  obj.dirty = true;
});

var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var text = new fabric.IText('Sample Text', {
  left: 50,
  top: 100,
  fontFamily: 'arial',
  fill: '#333',
  fontSize: 50
});
canvas.add(text);
canvas.setActiveObject(text);
```

```css
canvas{
  border-width: 1pz;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<a class="dropdown-item" id="bold" style="font-weight: bold;">Bold</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" id="italic" style="text-decoration: italic;"><em>Italic</em></a>
<a class="dropdown-item" id="underline" style="text-decoration: underline;">Underline</a>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.20/fabric.js"></script>
<div id="canvases">
  <canvas id="c" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Beautiful. Would you mind explaining why each shouldn't have `obj.dirty = true;`? Why was this necessary for this one handler? And thank you.

Comment: @code4ever if you set `dirty = true`, it will refresh the cache canvas with the new added property on next render call.